# SQL Server Query Internal Table using name

Tags: sql-server

I would like to be able to see the content of an internal table.

Running this query

```
SELECT * from [sys].[change_tracking_901578250]
```

returns

```
Invalid object name 'sys.change_tracking_901578250'.
```

However, I am able to do the following..

```
sp_spaceused 'sys.change_tracking_901578250'
```

I need to be able to use the table name because I am not allowed to execute the CHANGETABLE function in a SqlDependency (C#)

```
CHANGETABLE(CHANGES Product, @minid)
```

My goal is to update a table based on the changes tracked by the ChangeTracking...

Comment: Check if user you use to connect db can read `sys` schema

Comment: are u sure the tables exists? maybe you can check with SELECT * from sys.change_tracking_tables

Comment: @lad2025 Yes I can read sys schema.

Comment: @GuidoG The table exits. As I mentionned, I can get the space used by the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured those internal tables can be accessed using Dedicated Administrator Connection (DAC). Therefor, I was forced to change the way I track changes in my database..

For more info, visit [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068(v=sql.105).aspx)